# How to locate XML data between nodes by XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSL, sorry to ask a silly question. How to locate data 'a' using XSL.

```
<A>
  <B>b</B>
  <C>c</C>
  a
  <D>d</D>
  <E>e</E>
</A>
```

I have searched for answers and learned to locate b, c, d, e by using Xpath. When comes to data a, I failed. I tried to use path A but it displayed all data including b c a d e. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities:

- `/A/text()`
  *this selects all child text nodes of `<A>`*
- `/A/text()[not(normalize-space() = '')]`
  *this selects all non-empty text children of `<A>`*
- `/A/text()[3]`
  *this selects the `'\n  a\n  '` node from your example specifically* (note that there are whitespace-only text nodes that count as well!)
- `/A/C/following-sibling::text()[1]`
  *this selects the `'\n  a\n'` node from your example specifically*
- `//text()[following-sibling::* or preceding-sibling::*]`
  *this selects all text nodes that have element siblings (i.e. mixed content)*

Depends on how you look at it.

Comment: Be advised that this is a relatively brittle solution. You should use a more specific XPath expression if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like //A/. not work?  I'm no expert, but this should show the text for the A node only, I believe.